# Search solr keywords "OR", "AND" AND "will report errors [Hybris integrate solr]

Tags: java, solr

**Search solr keywords "OR", "AND" AND "will report errors.
My local environment was good, but STG and DEV failed,So what's the solution.

It is feasible to translate the search conditions by adding "\" before the search conditions.
Are there any other solutions? Thanks.

Below is the error log:**

```
 ERROR [hCSHTTP10] [SolrSearchRequestResponsePopulator] Exception while executing SOLR search
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.453 |  de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.FacetSearchException: Error from server at http://10.246.88.191:8983/solr: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse '(skus_string_mv:(OR^40.0 OR *OR*^20.0)) OR (code_string:(OR^40.0 OR *OR*^20.0)) OR (styleNumber_string:(OR^40.0 OR *OR*^20.0)) OR (collectionName_text_en_mv:(or^160.0 OR *or*^80.0)) OR (collectionName_text_zh_mv:(or^160.0 OR *or*^80.0)) OR (keywords_text_en:(or^240.0 OR *or*^120.0)) OR (keywords_text_zh:(or^240.0 OR *or*^120.0)) OR (name_text_en:(or^220.0 OR *or*^110.0)) OR (name_text_zh:(or^220.0 OR *or*^110.0)) OR (categoryName_text_en_mv:(or^200.0)) OR (categoryName_text_zh_mv:(or^200.0)) OR (category_string_mv:(or^160.0 OR *or*^80.0)) OR (colorFamilyName_text_en:(or^140.0 OR *or*^70.0)) OR (colorFamilyName_text_zh:(or^140.0 OR *or*^70.0)) OR (swatchColorDisplayName_text_en:(or^140.0 OR *or*^70.0)) OR (swatchColorDisplayName_text_zh:(or^140.0 OR *or*^70.0)) OR (legacySkuCode_string:(OR^40.0 OR *OR*^20.0))': Encountered " <OR> "OR "" at line 1, column 17.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.453 | Was expecting one of:
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.453 |     <NOT> ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.453 |     "+" ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.453 |     "-" ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.453 |     <BAREOPER> ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.453 |     "(" ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.453 |     "*" ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.453 |     <QUOTED> ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.453 |     <TERM> ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.454 |     <PREFIXTERM> ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.454 |     <WILDTERM> ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.454 |     <REGEXPTERM> ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.454 |     "[" ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.454 |     "{" ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.454 |     <LPARAMS> ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.454 |     "filter(" ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.454 |     <NUMBER> ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.454 |     <TERM> ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/25 03:58:19.454 |     "*" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

use this `\\AND`

and in my opinion those are stop words you don't need to search for them, if you want to use them as logic operator then just do it: q=java AND Python